# two questions about writing executable file packer

Tags: assembly, exe, reverse-engineering, inline-assembly, portable-executable

I am trying to write my first PE packer with C++ , i studied about PE quite well and now i want to begin write my stub in pure assembly but i have two questions.

1. If I compile a very short assembly code like 2 lines of code , when we open the exe file does the operation system  try to copy those lines on a free space of ram and then set a pointer to the starting point using  Instruction Pointer (IP) ? in this case does os only try to do this since it is pure assembly ?
2. i am going to XOR all other sections and keep all those data in dummysection1 and keep my pure assebly code in dummysection2 and change address of entry point to dummysection2 , how ever i have a little problem, should i add more space in ram and run this code in that RVA and using pure assembly to XOR dummysection1 datas on the other parts of RVA and then jump to OEP?

Comment: You should remove the part about "Can you provide me with some good resources to study them?" - this is off topic for SO.  We can answer specific programming related questions, but we cannot provide a list of books.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad.

Comment: but just in case how sohuld i know where i can extend my knowledge? i am very new.

Comment: @m0rfl1ng What is your discord tag?

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO my discord is m0rfl1ng#1827

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the one part of your question which is on-topic for Stack Overflow:

> If I compile a very short assembly code like 2 lines of code, when we open the exe file does the operation system try to copy those lines on a free space of ram and then set a pointer to the starting point using Instruction Pointer (IP)? in this case does os only try to do this since it is pure assembly?

When you compile (actually "assemble") assembly code, it becomes binary executable code, sometimes called "object code" or "machine code."  This is a somewhat straightforward translation from the textual assembly language to the more efficiently packed (but not really human readable) code the processor can execute.

If you then link that machine code into an executable, it will be placed in a part of the file labeled the "text segment" aka "code segment."  Don't be confused here, the "text" segment is not really strings, despite the name.  For more on this, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/february/inside-windows-win32-portable-executable-file-format-in-detail which describes the Win32 executable file format, including where the executable code lives.

When the operating system (or more properly, the loader) runs your executable, it copies (at least some of) the executable code into RAM, sets the program counter (aka instruction pointer) to a place which is known by convention, and then your code runs from there until it gives back control to the operating system, or until the OS takes control because it ran too long or did something bad.

Comment: oh i see , how can i inject my assembly code then should i inject it to the free space of text segment? i know you can add new section but so far i wan not able to do it. i mean if it is not really human readable then how i can do this?